# Javascript - How to convert numbers to String in an array and use If Statement

Tags: javascript, console-application, console.log

Ex: `arr = [1,1,2,3]`;

If the values is `1` , it should change to `red`

If the values is `2` , it should change to `blue`

If the values is `3` , it should change to `white`

Expected output:

```
arr = [red,red,blue,white]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can map your Array :

```
var nn = arr.map(e=> e == 1 ? e = "red" : e == 2 ? e = "blue" : e = "white")
```

Comment: is it possible to use the if else method?  I've tried several ways with the if else method but it doesn't work

Comment: this is if else statement, but in another way. but you can also use this:  arr.map(function (e){ 
if(e == 1) {return e = "red"};
if (e == 2 ) {return e = "blue"}
else {return e = "white"};
})

Answer (score 1):

Like so you are also able to filter out values that can't be mapped like 4 in this example.

```js
[1,1,2,3,4].map(number => {
  switch(number) {
      case 1: 
        return 'red'
      case 2: 
        return 'blue'
      case 3:
        return 'white'
      default:
        return undefined 
  }
}).filter(name => name)
```